# Powershell GUI - Button To Copy

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell GUI Script, and the final thing I need to do is add a button to copy user credentials to the clipboard.

Below, is the relevant code.

```
$ResultsCopy                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$ResultsCopy.text                = "Copy"
$ResultsCopy.width               = 185
$ResultsCopy.height              = 29
$ResultsCopy.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(160,349)
$ResultsCopy.Font                = 'Georgia,10'
$ResultsCopy.Add_Click({ ResultsCopy })

Function ResultsCopy
{"
 Display Name: $DisplayName
 Username: $SAMAccountName
 Email: $Mail 
 Password: $passwordvalue" | clip}
```

It then copies to the clipboard as

```
 Display Name:
 Username:
 Email:
 Password:
```

No Data is actually grabbed for some reason.

It should look like the following

```
 Display Name: James Timms
 Username: James.Timms
 Email: James.Timms@Mail.com
 Password: SuperSecurePassword69
```

Hopefully somebody has an idea

**Was asked to clarify the parameters / variables so below i will do so**

```
$DisplayName = $UCFirstNameParam + " " + $UCsurNameParam
$Mail = $UCFirstNameParam + "." + $UCsurNameParam + "@" + "annodata.co.uk"
$MailAlias = $UCFirstNameParam + "." + $UCsurNameParam + "@" + $DNSRoot2

$SInitial = $UCsurNameParam[0]
$Initial = $UCFirstNameParam[0]
$SAMAccountName = $UCFirstNameParam + "." + $UCsurNameParam
$SAMAccountLower = $SAMAccountName.ToLower()
$UserPrincipalName = $UCFirstNameParam + "." + $UCsurNameParam

$defaultname = $SAMAccountName
$email = $UCFirstNameParam + "." + $UCsurNameParam
$i = 1

$NewUserParams = @{
path                  = "OU=Bracknell,OU=Sites,DC=annodata,DC=co,DC=uk"
SamAccountName        = $SAMAccountName
Name                  = $SAMAccountName
DisplayName           = $DisplayName
GivenName             = $UCFirstNameParam
Surname               = $UCSurnameParam
EmailAddress          = $Mail
UserPrincipalName     = "$SAMAccountName@annodata.co.uk"
Description           = $UCRoleParam
ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
PasswordNeverExpires  = $false
AccountPassword       = $password
Enabled               = $true

$UCFirstNameParamLong                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$UCFirstNameParamLong.Text            = $UCFirstName.Text
$UCFirstNameParamLong.Location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180,100)
$UCFirstNameParamLong.AutoSize        = $true
$UCFirstNameParamLong.Font            = 'Georgia,10'

$UCSurnameParamLong                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$UCSurnameParamLong.Text            = $UCSurname.Text
$UCSurnameParamLong.Location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180,150)
$UCSurnameParamLong.AutoSize        = $true
$UCSurnameParamLong.Font            = 'Georgia,10'

$UCRoleParamLong                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$UCRoleParamLong.Text            = $UCRole.Text
$UCRoleParamLong.Location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180,200)
$UCRoleParamLong.AutoSize        = $true
$UCRoleParamLong.Font            = 'Georgia,10'

$UCLocationParamLong                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$UCLocationParamLong.Text            = $UCSiteSelection.Text
$UCLocationParamLong.Location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(180,250)
$UCLocationParamLong.AutoSize        = $true
$UCLocationParamLong.Font            = 'Georgia,10'

$UCFirstNameParam = $UCFirstNameParamLong.Text
$UCSurnameParam = $UCSurnameParamLong.Text
$UCRoleParam = $UCRoleParamLong.Text
$UCLocationParam = $UCLocationParamLong.Text
```

Comment: The `catch` is missing its `Try`

Comment: @T-Me

Only in here.

I removed the try, catch in this page as it's not important as i was only attempting to catch the error. In the actual script it's not like this at all

I have amended this on the post above.

Comment: try `$ResultsCopy.Add_Click({ write-host "$DisplayName is here"  })` to check the variable.

Comment: Can you show where you are getting the value for one of the properties. Like Display name and how you are declaring it as a variable

Comment: If you have `$var = $TextBox.Text` or something like that, the variable needs to be updated when you press a button or it will remain in the state of its creation (when the textbox was empty)

Comment: @ArcSet Sorry for the long delay, i was on my lunch break at work.

The properties, i will add below the current post

Comment: @T-Me $displayname isn't being detected

Comment: Do you think it's worth throwing this into a pastebin for you guys to fully analyse ?

Comment: @JamesTimms It is frowned on to post external links to code. As those links will could fail and then the post is worthless to future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out now.

Turns out that I did a stupid.

Since i'm working with functions, i forgot that i had to define a global variable.

I declared these, and now it works perfectly

Comment: i am not a big fan of global variables. This issue is quickly resolved by just putting the variables in order. But if it works it works....

Answer (score 0):

Include

```
$UCFirstNameParam = $UCFirstNameParamLong.Text
$UCSurnameParam = $UCSurnameParamLong.Text
$UCRoleParam = $UCRoleParamLong.Text
$UCLocationParam = $UCLocationParamLong.Text
```

in your click event/function:

```
Function ResultsCopy
{
    $UCFirstNameParam = $UCFirstNameParamLong.Text
    $UCSurnameParam = $UCSurnameParamLong.Text
    $UCRoleParam = $UCRoleParamLong.Text
    $UCLocationParam = $UCLocationParamLong.Text
     "
     Display Name: $DisplayName
     Username: $SAMAccountName
     Email: $Mail 
     Password: $passwordvalue
     " | clip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is how u declared the variables based on how you pasted them.
In powershell things are read from top to bottom.

Here is a prime example of out of order variables calling

```
$DisplayName = $UCFirstNameParam + " " + $UCSurNameParam
$UCFirstNameParam = $UCFirstNameParamLong.Text
$UCSurnameParam = $UCSurnameParamLong.Text
```

Why this will not work. 
$DisplayName will not equal anything but the " " becuase you have not declared what $UCFirstNameParam and $UCSurNameParam equal.

The fix would be to create the variables when they are assigned the value

```
$UCFirstNameParam = $UCFirstNameParamLong.Text
$UCSurnameParam = $UCSurnameParamLong.Text
$DisplayName = $UCFirstNameParam + " " + $UCSurNameParam
```

Comment: I know this is usually the case, so my first thing was to order it correctly.

However, this did not work in my case.

Completely forgot about global variables, and this fixed the issue that I was having.

Comment: I see in ur code you posted above the variables are out of order. I again state that global is not a good substitute for well made script.